# I need to write some chinese characters to copy paste

Tags: characters

I need help writing this on my computer, so I can Copy/paste and if its possible, whats the meaning of it, thanks alot guys! here is the image:
[image: chinese characters]

Comment: Haha, it seems a Q(cute) action figure of Lina Inverse. 1) Q版手办-莉娜-B款. 2) Q版主题手办 莉娜. But you've been to a wrong place, this question will be closed.

Comment: omg seriously? thanks alot, tought this was the correct place to ask =( ty anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q版主题手办-莉娜-B款

```
Q版 (Cute Version) 
主题 (Theme) 
手办 (not sure about this one, maybe manual) 
莉娜 (a name: Lina) 
B版 (B Version)
```

Comment: `手办`:`Garage Kit`. See this:[手办](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%89%8B%E5%8A%9E)